# Callbacks in using the GSR plugin with GeoServer

Tags: geoserver

I am looking at using GeoServer with the GSR plugin to mimic the normal ESRI rest MapServer endpoints.  It looks like it doesn't handle the callback requests:

The requests the ESRI web mapping frameworks use for the initial handshake include a "callback=something" parameter like so:
https://host/geoserver/gsr/services/ne/MapServer/2?f=json&callback=dojo_request_script_callbacks.dojo_request_script0

The GSR plugin isn't wrapping this up in a wrapper like I would expect:

```
dojo_request_script_callbacks.dojo_request_script0({snip});
```

But instead just dumping the JSON like there isn't a callback requested.
So:

```
"currentVersion":10.51,"id":2,"type":"Feature Layer","name":"countries","defaultVisibility":false,"definitionExpression":"","description":"Country boundaries on land and offshore.","displayField":"WIKIDATAID","copyrightText":"","relationships":[],"subLayers":[],"types": <snip>
```

Is there another plugin/option I need to include with GeoServer to it wrap the callbacks like I would expect?